# Are deferred tasks parallelized in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parallel-processing, deferred

I have a CRON job which imports everyday a list of 20 fresh files from a S3 bucket to a GS bucket.

Here is my code:

```
import webapp2
import yaml
from google.appengine.ext import deferred


class CronTask(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        with open('/my/config/file') as file:
            config_dict = yaml.load(file_config_file)
        for file_to_load in config_dict:
            deferred.defer(my_import_function, file_to_load)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', CronTask)
], debug=True)
```

My question: Is this loading job parallelised automatically by the queue process using the `deferred.defer` function, or shall I paralelize it myself?

If we are in the second case, what techniques can I use to parallelize this loading process efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on your module's [scaling settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration), and the queue's [processing settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue?hl=en#Python_Defining_push_queues_and_processing_rates) but by default tasks will execute with some parallelism.

Comment: Could you give me some example of config please?

Comment: The task queue link Greg posted has examples around `max_concurrent_requests`. As long as your `deferred.defer` is pointing to a `queue_name` that has  `max_concurrent_requests` > 0 (or omitted) in your `queue.yaml` then you will be fine.

Comment: Lets suppose that the tasks I sent to my Queue takes 2 hours each to be done. Since a task in a push queue has 10 minutes to complete, It may not be a good solution. What would be a good practice for such very long treatments, in order to treat them in a parallel way, but with unlimited time limit so they have time to finish?

Comment: Design your tasks to track their progress and as they near 10 min runtime, they schedule a new task. In addition if a task was to fail sometime you can continue from a known point. Remember tasks need to be idempotent, they could due to failure be asked to run again.

Comment: see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#the_rate_of_task_execution